# Import .zip file to mongoDB in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoimport, mongorestore

I am using Ubuntu.

I was searching for importing dump.zip file to MongoDB, but only getting .json/.bson files import or to a specific collection.

Can someone please help me out importing a .zip file to MongoDB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not come across a use case u upload zip files. But you use the "unzip <filename.zip> in terminal" to unzip and then import using mongorestore/mongodump.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this list of steps:

1. unzip folder_name.zip
2. mongorestore --db database_name dump/folder_name

Answer (score 1):

On Mac that work for me, the folder contain many files .gz

```
 mongorestore --gzip -d  MydataBaseName MyFolder/
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. This worked on my mac m1.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to unzip your zip file then try this command

```
mongorestore --db YOUR_DATABASE_NAME --verbose ./FOLDER_NAME
```

**Restoring MongoDB Backups Using mongorestore**

It is essential to have an efficient and reliable data restoration method after backing up data during the backup and restore process. Consider the differences:

- A properly configured restoration method means users can successfully
  restore the data to the previous state.
- A poor restoration method
  makes the whole backup process ineffective, by preventing users from
  accessing and restoring the backed-up data.

> The mongorestore command is the sister command of the mongodump command. You can restore the dumps (backups) created by the mongodump command into a MongoDB instance using the mongorestore command.

> The mongorestore utility offers support for MongoDB versions 4.4, 4.2, 4.0, and 3.6. It may also work with earlier versions of MongoDB, but compatibility is not guaranteed.

> **Additionally**, mongorestore supports a multitude of platforms and operating systems ranging from x86 to s390x; you can see the full compatibility list in the **[official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#compatibility)**.